# Command prompt FTP to transfer Mp3 causing file to sound "garbled"

Tags: ftp

So I am using the FTP protocols to download an MP3 from our news center to our computer in the radio station. Its all setup with scheduled tasks and is automated. The news mp3 is coming in "garbled" sounding, almost like its playing backwards or something, I am having no problems using the same code to download from our weather center.

Also, it should be noted that I can download the News with an ftp client and the mp3 plays perfectly, its only when using the ftp protocol that it becomes an issue

The code is simple

open site.site.com

user username password

mget News-2.mp3

bye

I have messed with it and messed with it and tried multiple clients and other ways of downloading and its only using the FTP protocols that it screws up the file.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to set `binary` mode before doing the transfers so that music that happens to contain the code for linefeed and carriage returns is not `converted`.

Try using:

```
open site...
user username password
bi
mget ...
```

Also, try running `DIR New*mp3` in the FTP session and then running `ls -l *mp3` locally after `GETTING` the file, the sizes should be identical, but if they are different by a few bytes it is probably the line endings being dynamically `corrected` during the transfer.